In the sentence 'В лесу тихо' what case is the adjective?
I am guessing that it is instrumental case? Please confirm.

There's no adjective in this sentence.
It means "it's quiet in the woods" (or, literally, "it's quietly in the woods"). Тихо "quietly" in this case is a predicative adverb, and adverbs don't decline in Russian.
Compare it to English sentences like "it's soon" or "he's abroad". These are examples of predicative adverbs as well. You can't say "*a soon summer" or "*an abroad person".
Many concepts that in English are conveyed using adjectives and analytic constructs, in Russian are conveyed using predicative adverbs instead: мне холодно "I'm cold", мне скучно "I'm bored", мне трудно "I'm having a hard time" etc.

The word тихо is an adverb formed from тихий. Adverbs do not have cases.
It's the predicate of this subjectless sentence.
